# How to get values of dynamically generated controls and call their events in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-webpages

This is my code in which i created dynamic controls in 2 panels.
Now I want to get values from these dynamic controls. I also generated dynamic button and its event but when i click in button it will not hit break point and page is post back.I read on internet that i have to generate control or store their values into PreInit of Asp.net page life cycle. But i can't understand it. If anyone know about it Reply me.
Thanks.

```
  public void showControls(string p)
    {

        Button btn = new Button();
        List<string> lblUD = getUserDetails(p);
        List<string> lblli = getWebPagesName();
        for (int i = 0; i < o; i++)
        {

            HtmlAnchor ha = new HtmlAnchor();
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
            Label lbl = new Label();
            cb.Checked = false;

            cb.ID = "cb" + i.ToString();
            cb.Text = "Allow";

            lbl.Text = lblli[i].ToString();

            lbl.ID = "lbl" + i.ToString();
            ha.Controls.Add(lbl);
            ha.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
            lbl.Style.Add("line-height", "28px");
            //lbl.Style.Add("border", "1px solid");
            //cb.Style.Add("border", "1px solid");

            lblPanel.Controls.Add(ha);

            //lblPanel.Controls.Add( new LiteralControl("<br/>"));

            cb.Style.Add("line-height", "24px");
            cbPanel.Controls.Add(cb);
            cbPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));    
            Label2.Enabled = true;
            Label2.Text = "<h2>Assign Roles</h2>";
        }
        for (int s = 0; s < lblUD.Count; s++)
        {
            Label lblud = new Label();
            lblud.ID = "lblud" + s.ToString();
            lblud.Text = lblUD[s].ToString();
            lblud.Style.Add("line-height", "28px");
            userdetailPanel.Controls.Add(lblud);
            userdetailPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
        }
        btn.ID = "btn_Submit";
        btn.Text = "Save";
        btn.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btn_Submit_click);
        cbPanel.Controls.Add(btn);

    }
```

Comment: If the controls don't exist when the page is created and the POST data loaded into them they will not have any values. Where are you calling this method from?

Comment: controls are generated on textbox text changed event.

Comment: So it seems the controls are not created in page load itself and created in one of the textbox text changed event rite? Can you elaborate your question. Because, in the first for loop, from where populating the value of "o". And tell me, when textbox text changing event only you can know which the controls need to create ?

Comment: @Kavin see this. It is my old post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45212963/how-to-get-data-from-dynamically-generated-controls-and-insert-them-into-sql-dat.  When i press dynamically created button it is not entering in button event.

Comment: @SyedUsama You are not understanding. You should create the dynamic controls in page_load or Init events. Otherwise, the controls behave unexpectedly. see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/317794/how-to-dynamically-create-controls-in-asp-net-by-using-visual-c--net  so Just answer my question in previous comment.

Comment: @Kavin I am creating controls on textbox text changed event.

Comment: @SyedUsama See If you create the controls in textbox text changed event then the the controls may behave unexpectedly. You should create the controls in Page_Load/Init event.

Comment: @Kavin ok.I will try to make logic that i will create these controls on page load.